# GCP Cloud Build failed with error: Caller does not have permission or the resource may not exist

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, nestjs, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to deploy a nestjs application on a monorepo to GCD CI/CD "Cloud Build API". I pushed the images to Artifact Registry successfully.

My **cloudbuild.yaml** file looks like below:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builder/docker'
    args:
      [
        'build',
        '-t',
        'europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/driven-atrium-414021/reservations/production',
        '-f',
        'apps/reservations/Dockerfile',
        '.',
      ]
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builder/docker'
    args:
      [
        'push',
        'europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/driven-atrium-414021/reservations/production',
      ]

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builder/docker'
    args:
      [
        'build',
        '-t',
        'europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/driven-atrium-414021/auth/production',
        '-f',
        'apps/auth/Dockerfile',
        '.',
      ]
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builder/docker'
    args:
      [
        'push',
        'europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/driven-atrium-414021/auth/production',
      ]

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builder/docker'
    args:
      [
        'build',
        '-t',
        'europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/driven-atrium-414021/notifications/production',
        '-f',
        'apps/notifications/Dockerfile',
        '.',
      ]
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builder/docker'
    args:
      [
        'push',
        'europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/driven-atrium-414021/notifications/production',
      ]

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builder/docker'
    args:
      [
        'build',
        '-t',
        'europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/driven-atrium-414021/payments/production',
        '-f',
        'apps/payments/Dockerfile',
        '.',
      ]
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builder/docker'
    args:
      [
        'push',
        'europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/driven-atrium-414021/payments/production',
      ]
```

I tried running $gcloud auth configure-docker gcr.io  according to this [source](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Developer-Tools/Permission-quot-artifactregistry-repositories-downloadArtifacts/m-p/475349) and I tried to play with permissions per other suggestions (new to GCP here) with no luck.

I got *Caller does not have permission or the resource may not exist*  even though my user has the admin/owner role, I checked the repositories exists in the Artifact Repository. Here is a screenshot of my error from cloud build:
[image]

Any help on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your user’s permissions are not important here, cloud build uses a default service account (or you can overwrite it) and it needs to have the appropriate permissions. So, check the service account and assign the right permissions.

Comment: can you please guide me how to do this?

Comment: I went to cloud build settings and found that the account service has the "Cloud Build"+"Cloud Run" + "Service Accounts" roles enabled.
I also checked it from IAM -> Permissions  and tried to give the service agent account all relevant roles I could think of but not luck

Comment: Check your cloudbuild.yaml, check if the names should be `gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker` instead of `gcr.io/cloud-builder/docker` as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/configure-cloud-build). Also, take a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783869/why-am-i-seeing-this-error-error-gcloud-run-deploy-permission-denied-the-c) as it covers this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-cloud-run#before_you_begin).

Comment: @Marra, I found the solution and when I came to answer my question I found your comment! Please answer my question to take the credit for it. (I will delete mine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **cloudbuild.yaml**, change the names from `gcr.io/cloud-builder/docker` to `gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker` as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/configure-cloud-build).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, as @Marra commented, that the problem was mistyping the name of the cloud-builder/docker while it should be cloud-builders/docker (I missed the "s")

I find it strange that GCP error message didn't differentiate between a missing resource and an inaccessible existing one!